# Django drf get List<String> from Android but this is string

Tags: android, python, django, django-rest-framework

django 2.0.2 python3.4

django view.py

```
class Test(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ''
    serializer_class = BaseSerializer

    def create(self,request):
        print(request.data.dict())
        return Response(0)
```

androidSend

```
@Field("Tests") List<String> Tests
```

Log in Android return `[1,2,3]`

but django `print(request.data.dict())`

return `{"Tests":"3"}`

not List just Str

how to get List from Android to django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved request.data to request.POST